# LoadError: libffi.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory running Rails

Tags: 20.04, ruby, rails

I am having trouble with creating a new rails project. When I run `rails new project_name` it comes to the `rails webpacker:install` it fails with the following error:

```
LoadError: libffi.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/matija/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi_c.so
/home/matija/Documents/learning-rails/course-project/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
/home/matija/Documents/learning-rails/course-project/Rakefile:4:in `<main>'
/home/matija/Documents/learning-rails/course-project/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:/home/matija/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
<internal:/home/matija/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
/home/matija/Documents/learning-rails/course-project/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
<internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
/home/matija/Documents/learning-rails/course-project/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:2:in `load'
bin/rails:2:in `<main>'

Caused by:
LoadError: cannot load such file -- 3.0/ffi_c
/home/matija/Documents/learning-rails/course-project/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
/home/matija/Documents/learning-rails/course-project/Rakefile:4:in `<main>'
/home/matija/Documents/learning-rails/course-project/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:/home/matija/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
<internal:/home/matija/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
/home/matija/Documents/learning-rails/course-project/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
<internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
/home/matija/Documents/learning-rails/course-project/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:2:in `load'
bin/rails:2:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I am using ASDF for ruby version management.

I tried many solutions like uninstalling and installing the gem, running `gem pristine` and some other methods that are provided on SO and here.

Comment: `libffi.so.8` is provided by the package `libffi8ubuntu1` ... which is available for Ubuntu 21.04 . ..... and for Ubuntu 21.10, the package name is `libffi8`  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=impish&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libffi.so.8 . ............. Please specify Ubuntu version : In your question.

Comment: Testing with Ubuntu 20.04 : Installing the Ubuntu 21.10 `libffi8` ......... `sudo gdebi libffi8_3.4.2-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb` https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/amd64/libffi8/download .......... No issues, no dependencies.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [@Knud Larsen](https://askubuntu.com/users/475620/knud-larsen) for [their comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1377139/loaderror-libffi-so-8-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-director/1442776#comment2372052_1377139), this worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04:

```shell
wget http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libf/libffi/libffi8_3.4.2-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i ./libffi8_3.4.2-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb
```

Comment: `wget http://http.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libf/libffi/libffi8_3.4.4-1_amd64.deb` worked for me, after searching [here](https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/libffi8/download)

Answer (score 1):

When I was working on a Rails project I realized there was a difference in versions between the system's and the project's one, thus my solution was matching the two by running these commands:

```
gem uninstall ffi 
gem install ffi -v 1.15.0 -- --disable-system-libffi
```